Separate sliders for each container with a parent with a constrained height
So I have the below piece of code and wanted to achieve two scrolling containers with div#parent contained ad 75vh
But what I get is a stretched parent to fit the sidebar and content.
I don't understand why this is happening as I have added overflow for both elements.
Could somebody point me in the right direction?
<body>
    <div id="parent" style="display: flex; max-height: 75vh; min-height: 30vh; width: 75vh; background-color: beige;">
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; flex-grow: 1;">
            <div>
                <p>Head</p>
            </div>
            <div style="display: flex;">
                <div id="nav" style="width: 250px; background-color: aquamarine;">
                    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 0px;">
                        <p style="height: 800px; background-color: blueviolet;">asdasd</p>
                    </div>
                    <button>asdasd</button>
                </div>
                <div id="content" style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: aliceblue; overflow-y: scroll;">
                    <p style="height: 1800px; background-color: brown;">main</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color: darkgrey;">
                footer
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

